# Javascript(addEventListener) not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I added my code to [Github](https://abdulazizs-hub.github.io/en/), everything worked then I found out that it does not work below iOS 13. But in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Abdulazis/full/NWbwGPV) it clearly works. Here it is

```js
window.onload = function () {
const target = document.querySelectorAll("[data-text-swap]");
  let touchEvent = "ontouchstart" in window ? "touchstart" : "click";
  for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    target[i].addEventListener(touchEvent,function () {
        target[i].closest(".group") ?.querySelector(".toggle_cont").toggleAttribute("visible");
        if (target[i].getAttribute("data-text-swap") == target[i].innerHTML) {
          target[i].innerHTML = target[i].getAttribute("data-text-original");
          target[i].classList.remove("cgray");
        } else {
          target[i].setAttribute("data-text-original", target[i].innerHTML);
          target[i].innerHTML = target[i].getAttribute("data-text-swap");
          target[i].classList.add("cgray");
        }
      },true
    );
  }
}
```

```css
a,abbr,acronym,address,applet,article,aside,audio,b,big,blockquote,body,canvas,caption,center,cite,code,dd,del,details,dfn,div,dl,dt,em,embed,fieldset,figcaption,figure,footer,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,header,hgroup,html,i,iframe,img,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,mark,menu,nav,object,ol,output,p,pre,q,ruby,s,samp,section,small,span,strike,strong,sub,summary,sup,table,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,time,tr,tt,u,ul,var,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}:focus{outline:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:after,blockquote:before,q:after,q:before{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none}input[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;resize:vertical}audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;max-width:100%}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden]{display:none}html{font-size:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%}a:focus{outline:thin dotted}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}img{border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic}figure{margin:0}form{margin:0}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}legend{border:0;padding:0;white-space:normal}button,input,select,textarea{font-size:100%;margin:0;vertical-align:baseline}button,input{line-height:normal}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type=button],input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}button,html,input,select,textarea{color:#222}::-moz-selection{background:#b3d4fc;text-shadow:none}::selection{background:#b3d4fc;text-shadow:none}img{vertical-align:middle}fieldset{border:0;margin:0;padding:0}textarea{resize:vertical}.chromeframe{margin:.2em 0;background:#ccc;color:#000;padding:.2em 0}a{text-decoration:none;color:#4b5a65}body{font-family:sans-serif;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;background-color:#f2f7fb;width:100%;height:100vh;margin:0;padding:0;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column}header{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;width:calc(100% - 30px);margin:26px auto 30px auto;max-width:1160px}.sidenav{display:none}.bigLogo{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:start;-ms-flex-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex:1;flex:1}.bigLogo img{width:341px;height:76px}.minLogo{display:none}.minLogo img{width:61px;height:60px}.link_list_open{display:none}.link_list{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex}.link_list ul{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex}.link_list ul li{color:#4b5a65;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;margin-right:55px}.link_list ul li a{font-weight:500;font-size:17px;line-height:28px;color:#485a65;min-height:28px}.cgray{color:#bdbdbd!important}.cred{color:#ff5441!important}.dropbtn{width:41px;height:41px;background:#fff;border:0;-webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(82,91,99,.06);box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(82,91,99,.06);padding:0;border-radius:8px}.dropdown{position:relative;display:inline-block}.dropdownContent{display:none;position:absolute;min-width:41px;-webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(82,91,99,.06);box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(82,91,99,.06);z-index:1;border-radius:0 0 8px 8px}.dropbtn span{font-weight:700;font-size:17px;line-height:41px;color:#181818}.dropdownContent a{font-weight:700;font-size:17px;line-height:20px;color:#181818;width:41px;height:35px;text-decoration:none;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;margin-top:1px;-webkit-padding-before:5px;padding-block-start:5px;background:#fff}.dropdownContent a:hover{background-color:#ff5441;color:#fff}.dropdownContent a:last-child{border-radius:0 0 8px 8px}.dropdown:hover .dropdownContent{display:block}.dropdown:hover .dropbtn{border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(82,91,99,.06);box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(82,91,99,.06)}main{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.main_title{font-weight:700;font-size:36px;line-height:50px;color:#181818;margin:0 0 30px}.group{background:#fff;-webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 35px rgba(82,91,99,.06);box-shadow:0 15px 35px rgba(82,91,99,.06);border-radius:25px;min-width:300px;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around;padding:30px;max-height:620px;min-height:490px}.group:first-child{margin-left:0}.group:last-child{margin-right:0}.about_group,.main_group{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between;-ms-flex-item-align:center;align-self:center;-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-flow:row nowrap;flex-flow:row nowrap;width:calc(100% - 30px);max-width:1160px}.about_group{-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-flow:column nowrap;flex-flow:column nowrap;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.group_logo{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;height:65px;width:240px;margin:0 auto 30px}.group_logo img{width:240px}.group_text{font-size:17px;line-height:30px;color:#64707a;width:270px;height:270px;-ms-flex-item-align:center;-ms-grid-row-align:center;align-self:center}.group_btn{background:-o-linear-gradient(left,#abb0c2 0,#b9c5e6 100%);background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top, right top,color-stop(0, #abb0c2),to(#b9c5e6));background:linear-gradient(90deg,#abb0c2 0,#b9c5e6 100%);-webkit-box-shadow:0 10px 25px #cdd2e1;box-shadow:0 10px 25px #cdd2e1;border-radius:25px;max-width:250px;max-height:50px;margin:25px auto 0;width:-webkit-fit-content;width:-moz-fit-content;width:fit-content}.btn_text{font-weight:700;font-size:17px;line-height:26px;text-align:center;color:#fff;padding:14px 31.5px 10px;display:block}footer{margin:15px auto 0 auto;padding-bottom:30px}.copyright{font-size:14px;line-height:26px;color:#a5afb8}.light_group{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;-webkit-box-align:start;-ms-flex-align:start;align-items:flex-start;-ms-flex-item-align:start;align-self:flex-start;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column}.light_group:first-child{margin-right:23px}.light_group:last-child{-ms-flex-preferred-size:30%;flex-basis:30%;-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex:1;flex:1}iframe{border:10px solid #fff;border-radius:25px;width:-webkit-fill-available;min-height:288px;max-width:658px;max-height:560px;height:50vh;margin-left:auto}.CallPhoto{margin:10px 30px 10px 0}.min_group{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;min-width:155px;-webkit-box-pack:start;-ms-flex-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}.min_group address,.min_group figcaption{font-size:17px;line-height:28px;color:#181818}.light_group .min_group:nth-child(2) a{text-decoration:underline;color:#5398ff}.numbers{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-flow:column wrap;flex-flow:column wrap}.members_img{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;width:-webkit-fill-available;min-width:320px;max-width:1140px;border:10px solid #fff;-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0 15px 35px rgba(82, 91, 99, .06));filter:drop-shadow(0 15px 35px rgba(82, 91, 99, .06));border-radius:25px}.logo_text{font-size:17px;line-height:28px;color:#4b5a65;max-width:960px;margin-top:30px}.logo_text span{font-weight:900}.btn_show{display:none;border:0;background-color:transparent;font-weight:700;font-size:16px;line-height:26px;text-align:center;color:#ff413e}@media all and (max-width:1130px) and (min-width:1060px){.group{padding:30px 20px}}@media all and (max-width:1060px) and (min-width:1022px){.group{padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px}}@media all and (min-width:1023px){.btn_show{max-height:0;margin:auto;opacity:0}.toggle_cont{-webkit-transition:0s;-o-transition:0s;transition:0s;max-height:400px!important;margin:0 auto!important;opacity:1!important}}@media all and (max-width:1022px){*{-webkit-transition:0s;-o-transition:0s;transition:0s}.toggle_cont{max-height:225px;-webkit-transition:all .5s linear;-o-transition:all .5s linear;transition:all .5s linear;overflow:hidden;}.toggle_cont *{max-height:-webkit-max-content!important;max-height:-moz-max-content!important;max-height:max-content!important}[visible]{-webkit-transition:all .5s linear;-o-transition:all .5s linear;transition:all .5s linear;max-height:0!important}main{min-height:initial!important}.group{width:75%;margin:15px auto;min-height:120px;padding:30px}.group:first-child{margin-top:0;margin-left:auto}.group:last-child{margin-right:auto}.group_btn{margin:25px auto 30px}.main_group,.about_group{-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-flow:column nowrap;flex-flow:column nowrap;width:100%}.group_text{width:auto;height:auto}.bigLogo,.link_list{display:none}.minLogo{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex}.link_list_open{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;cursor:pointer}header{width:calc(75% + 60px);margin:12px auto 20px auto;-webkit-box-pack:justify;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between}.link_list{display:none}.sidenav{height:100%;width:0;position:fixed;z-index:3;top:0;left:0;background-color:rgba(242,247,251,.7);-webkit-backdrop-filter:blur(25px);backdrop-filter:blur(25px);overflow-x:hidden;-webkit-transition:.5s;-o-transition:.5s;transition:.5s;display:block}.c100per{width:100%}.sidenav a{font-weight:700;font-size:30px;line-height:80px;padding:4px 8px 4px 15px;text-decoration:none;color:#181818;display:block;-webkit-transition:.3s;-o-transition:.3s;transition:.3s;width:-webkit-max-content;width:-moz-max-content;width:max-content}.sidenav a:hover{color:rgba(24,24,24,.5)}iframe{width:658px}.light_group:first-child{margin:0 auto 15px}.members_img{width:calc(75% + 50px)}.logo_text{width:calc(75% + 60px)}.btn_show{display:block;z-index:2}}@media all and (max-width:768px){.group{margin-bottom:0;min-width:230px;-ms-flex-pack:distribute;justify-content:space-around}.toggle_cont{max-height:405px}.about_group{width:100%}.members_img{border:0;-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0 15px 35px rgba(82, 91, 99, .06));filter:drop-shadow(0 15px 35px rgba(82, 91, 99, .06));border-radius:0;margin:0;width:100%}.main_title{font-size:26px;margin-bottom:9px}.light_group:last-child{margin:0;width:100%}iframe{width:calc(75% + 40px);margin:0 auto;height:43.15vh}.btn_show::after{display:block}.light_group:first-child{width:calc(75% + 60px)}footer{padding-bottom:25px}}.arrow{border:solid #ff413e;border-width:0 3px 3px 0;display:inline-block;padding:3px;margin:5px}.up{-ms-transform:rotate(-135deg);transform:rotate(-135deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-135deg);border-color:#bdbdbd;margin-bottom:-2px}.down{-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);margin:3px}@media(max-height:802px) and (max-width:1023px){body{height:100%}}@media (max-height:861px) and (min-width:1024px) and (orientation:landscape){.gmin_height{min-height:430px}}@media (max-height:768px) and (min-width:1024px) and (orientation:landscape){.group_pad{padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px}}
```

```html
<section class="group gmin_height group_pad">
            <figure class="group_logo"><img src="" alt="Group Logo" /></figure>
            <div class="toggle_cont" visible>
                <p class="group_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt eveniet quae repellat dolores animi amet nemo quis tempora vero dignissimos fugit doloribus debitis sunt quod consequatur, quasi maiores sit mollitia. Porro facilis maxime unde esse et, labore magnam aliquam aspernatur. </p>
                <div class="group_btn"><a href="#" onclick="return false" class="btn_text">Coming soon</a>
                </div>
            </div><button class="btn_show" data-text-swap='Roll up<i class="arrow up"></i>'>Learn more<i
                    class="arrow down"></i></button>
        </section>
        <section class="group gmin_height group_pad">
            <figure class="group_logo"><img src="" alt="Group Logo" /></figure>
            <div class="toggle_cont" visible>
                <p class="group_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt eveniet quae repellat dolores animi amet nemo quis tempora vero dignissimos fugit doloribus debitis sunt quod consequatur, quasi maiores sit mollitia. Porro facilis maxime unde esse et, labore magnam aliquam aspernatur. </p>
                <div class="group_btn"><a href="#" onclick="return false" class="btn_text">Coming soon</a>
                </div>
            </div><button class="btn_show" data-text-swap='Roll up<i class="arrow up"></i>'>Learn more<i
                    class="arrow down"></i></button>
        </section>
        <section class="group gmin_height group_pad">
            <figure class="group_logo"><img src="" alt="Group Logo" /></figure>
            <div class="toggle_cont" visible>
                <p class="group_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt eveniet quae repellat dolores animi amet nemo quis tempora vero dignissimos fugit doloribus debitis sunt quod consequatur, quasi maiores sit mollitia. Porro facilis maxime unde esse et, labore magnam aliquam aspernatur. </p>
                <div class="group_btn"><a href="#" onclick="return false" class="btn_text">Coming soon</a>
                </div>
            </div><button class="btn_show" data-text-swap='Roll up<i class="arrow up"></i>'>Learn more<i
                    class="arrow down"></i></button>
        </section>
```

**By the way, the site must be opened on an iOS device below version 13 or here => https://appetize.io/demo?device=iphone5s&scale=75&orientation=portrait&osVersion=12.4 In full-screen mode it does not display correctly**

Tried to put `cursor: pointer` didn't help. And according to the terms of reference should not use any libraries, purely JavaScript.

***I would be very happy with any answer!*** **Thank You!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was iOS 12.5 didn't support my code. Had to change `<button>` in `<checkbox>` and used `#checkbox: checked`. The rest of the code in JavaScript works.